# CSS folder not appearing in sources with Gulp

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, compilation, gulp

I'm building a React page and using Gulp. My styles compile correctly to CSS and get saved locally in my destination folder (./build/css) as they should. However, when I inspect the page in the browser, the CSS folder isn't in the `build` folder, and none of my styles are showing up. Here's my app structure:

```
| build
    |- css
        |- style.css
    |- images
    |- main.js
| css
    |- style.styl
| resources
    |- images
| scripts
    |- components
        |- App.js
        |- etc...
    |- main.js
| gulpfile.js
| index.html
| package.json
```

And here's my gulpfile:

```
/*
  Styles Task
*/
gulp.task('styles',function() {
  // Compiles CSS
  gulp.src('css/style.styl')
    .pipe(stylus())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'))
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
});

/*
  Images
*/
gulp.task('images',function(){
  gulp.src('resources/images/**')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/images/'))
});

/*
  Browser Sync
*/
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        // we need to disable clicks and forms for when we test multiple rooms
        server : {},
        middleware : [ historyApiFallback() ],
        ghostMode: false
    });
});

function handleErrors() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  notify.onError({
    title: 'Compile Error',
    message: '<%= error.message %>'
  }).apply(this, args);
  this.emit('end'); // Keep gulp from hanging on this task
}

function buildScript(file, watch) {
  var props = {
    entries: ['./scripts/' + file],
    debug : true,
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {},
    transform:  [babelify.configure({stage : 0 })]
  };

  // watchify() if watch requested, otherwise run browserify() once
  var bundler = watch ? watchify(browserify(props)) : browserify(props);

  function rebundle() {
    var stream = bundler.bundle();
    return stream
      .on('error', handleErrors)
      .pipe(source(file))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
      .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
  }

  // listen for an update and run rebundle
  bundler.on('update', function() {
    rebundle();
    gutil.log('Rebundle...');
  });

  // run it once the first time buildScript is called
  return rebundle();
}

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return buildScript('main.js', false); // this will run once because we set watch to false
});

// run 'scripts' task first, then watch for future changes
gulp.task('default', ['images','styles','scripts','resources','browser-sync'], function() {
  gulp.watch('css/**/*', ['styles']); // gulp watch for CSS changes
  return buildScript('main.js', true); // browserify watch for JS changes
});
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure that you're including your styles in/on your HTML page, as, unless I'm terribly mistaken, their resources won't show up in the inspector.

Comment: Thank you Brynden! That was it!